# My pug files generating like a compressed file

Tags: html, pug-loader

While my files are being compressed, the teacher's files return normally.

Like This :

[image]

I tried to add .json file :

```
"editor.formatOnPaste": true,

"editor.formatOnType": true,
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  As it stands, there isn't enough information in your Question for us to help you.

Comment: What are you using to compile the Pug?

Comment: Also take a look at this guidance for [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)